# Java Eclipse, JavaSE-1.7 or jre7 when creating Runnable JAR File

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

When I start a new Java project in eclipse, the first popup screen allow me to choose which JRE to use.

I have 3 choices.

- Use an execution enviorment JRE: JavaSE1.7
- Use a project specific JRE:
- Use a default JRE(curretly 'jre7')

But when I use eclipse's build-in export to `Runnable JAR File` to create an executable JAR, the JAR file will only run (by double clicking) if I select `jre7` instead of eclipse's default choice `JavaSE1.7`

Can someone please tell me what is the difference between developing the java program in `JavaSE1.7` vs `jre7`? Or have I used the wrong method to create an executable JAR?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JRE stands for Java Runtime Environment. Without a JRE the Java Application cannot run. Imagine if you wanted to run an .exe file without the Windows OS. How would you manage that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to know are there any differences in choosing JavaSE1.7 vs jre7.

Comment: Post where jre7 and JavaSE 1.7 are actually located.  These are just "names" assigned to some JVM directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

**JavaSE 1.7** is an acronym for **Java to Standard Edition Version 1.7 or Version 7** (both are same), which is used for running on Desktops, Server,etc...

**JRE** is the **Runtime Environment** , in which the compiled java application runs...

```
JRE = JVM + API Bundles
```

The reason your executable jar runs, when you select the JRE instead of JSE is because, **JRE is the runtime environment (the sandbox) which is needed by the application to run**, not JSE.. JSE is just the acronym given to Java's Standard Edition.

**And for creating a Runnable jar in Eclipse follow the below method..**

```
Try this, this is the way to create a jar or runnable jar in eclipse

File -> Export-> Java ->Runnbale JAR file

Launch configuration : your Class containing the public static void main(String[] args)

Export destination : Target place

Library Handling:

Package required libraries into generated JAR

FINISH
```